# How to declare and use arrays in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a seemingly basic problem with C# arrays.  I am a beginner, but this is a *really* basic problem and it has had me in knots for more than half an hour now.  I am using C# 2010 Express.

This code:-

```
string[] motionCam = new string[8];
motionCam[1] = "Stop";
```

Reports the error:

> Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try
>   initializing with a 'new' expression)

Even basic array examples I copy and paste off of education web sites report this same error and I have no clue why.

Comment: That works for me. Also the first element in an array is at index 0 (`monitorCam[0] = "Stop";`). The last element in the array will be at index 7.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this particular code fragment, the error is elsewhere in your code.  What specific line is this error pointing out

Comment: That code looks perfectly fine, if it is inside a method. Did you accidentally paste it outside a method? The second line might give this error if you write it inside a class declaration, instead of inside a method. Please post the surrounding code.

Comment: Hello.  The error points to the 'motionCam[1] = "Stop";' line.  This code is in 'public partial class Form1 : Form' where I have placed other global variables - all working fine until now.  Thanks all for reading!

Comment: @Mark: That line has to be in a method.

Comment: @MarkMajor. As I answered, you can't write non-declaration statements at the class level. `motionCam[1] = "Stop";` is an assignment not a declaration, this why the compiler shouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the code you pasted is valid, your problem is something else.
Maybe you declared it in the class level.

`motionCam[1] = "Stop";` is an assignment not a declaration, this why the compiler shouts.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0f7a19c0-66fb-4e93-aba1-867e078a8b1e) question of someone who had that the same problem.

Bottom line is **You can't have non-declaration statements at the class level.**

Comment: Thank you.  I can work from that.  Very speedy response all you guys...  I have been reading this forum constantly and it's fantastic.  Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks to all.  This answer was the first to get me on the right track.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers that state that you cannot put that line of code in a class declaration but outside of a method body are correct. I thought it might be interesting to describe why you get the odd error message. The compiler is attempting desperately to try to figure out what you mean by `X[Y] = Z;`, and it assumes that what you meant was:

```
X[] F = Z;
```

That is, that you accidentally put the size of the array in the array declaration -- a very common error amongst C programmers who have recently learned C# -- and have omitted the name of the field.

The compiler therefore gives the most informative error that it can come up with: that you are probably a C programmer who has forgotten that the size of the array goes in the initializer, not the type declaration.

In this case that guess is completely wrong; the error here is that you've accidentally put a *statement* where a *field declaration* is expected. But most of the time, that's a reasonable guess.

Comment: The question is why the compiler guesses? If a human can get the real problem in a moment, so does the compiler. Am I wrong?

Comment: @gdoron: Sure, all you need to do is write a compiler that is as smart as a person, and you're set. Also, it needs to be able to do correct analysis of broken code in the time between keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

You're putting it in a class. (The second line)

Put it in a method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] motionCam = new string[8];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        motionCam[1] = "Stop";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's more to it than just that *one* line of code.  In any case, the specific thing the compiler is looking for (which may not be what **you** want) is something like:

```
var motionCam = new string[] { "Zero", "Stop" /*[1]*/, "Two" };
```

that's the `initializing with a 'new' expression` part.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this line inside a method (like the class constructor maybe):

```
motionCam[1] = "Stop";
```

The problem is that you are trying to create the array (which is fine) and then populate it (which is not) inside of the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is code that has to go inside a method. If you put it directly in a class, it gives that error.

The first line is a valid declaration, and thus is fine directly inside a class.
The second line is an assignment statement, and not a declaration. Thus it can only appear in a method, not directly in a class.

Put it into a method like this:

```
static void MyMethod()
{
  string[] motionCam = new string[8];
  motionCam[1] = "Stop";
}
```

If you put this code directly in a class, the C# compiler interprets `motionCam[1]` as a type. In C or C++ this would be an array of `motionCam` elements with size `1`. In C# it's invalid.